# Actionlink generating empty href when using URL GET parameter named 'page'

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, actionlink

I'm using this command:

```
@Html.ActionLink("A link", "Index", "Home", new { page = 10 }, new { @class = "active" })
```

It returns this:

```
<a class="active" href="">A link</a>
```

If I switch the paramater 'page' for 'pagee' (or any other name) it works as expected:

```
@Html.ActionLink("A link", "Index", "Home", new { pagee = 10 }, new { @class = "active" })

<a class="active" href="/?pagee=10">A link</a>
```

Here is some background and what I found so far. I was using a ASP .NET Core 2.2 MVC template with authentication "Individual User Accounts", I was getting this error and couldn't understand why, so I **created the same template without the authentication and then the problem disappeared**.

The only difference between the projects is that when you use authentication it creates a folder 'Areas' for Identity, maybe the parameter 'page' is reserved and can't be used, or a route problem? Sorry, I'm new to ASP .NET Core and don't know how to solve this.

I really want an authentication system for my project but if this problem persists I think I'll just go ahead without it. Please send halp.

Comment: Yes,"page" is [reserved routing name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#reserved-routing-names)

Comment: That's it! Now I understand why, I was using [ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging](https://github.com/sonnemaf/ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging/tree/master/src) for pagination, in it's implementation it uses page parameter. Do you have any other good tool for pagination system?

Comment: Do you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Then, you can try this [solution](https://github.com/sonnemaf/ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging/issues/21)

**Startup.cs**

in ConfigureServices method set:

```
services.AddPaging(options => {
    options.ViewName = "Bootstrap4"
    options.PageParameterName = "pageindex";
});
```

"Added a PageParameterName to the PagingOptions. You can set this to for example pageIndex. Make sure you also rename the parameters of your Actions."